# Totally new to Blender

Tags: physics, hair

Will Blender produce a real hair effect usings physics to add to Skyrim characters, I don't want blocky hair as in anime characters or will I need to learn 3DS Max instead.

Right, edited thanks to Duarte Farrjota Ramos

Comment: Hi, I would suggest that you please [edit your other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/168267/edit). It isn't necessarily a bad thing if a question is closed, it just means in this case that it needs to be a bit clearer so that other users can understand your goals. :) Adding a reference image to your post that shows the exact thing you want to achieve in blender will  help someone who may answer give a good answer that is actually helpful for you.

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question twice. I understand that as a new user this must be frustrating, but your original question was closed for a reason. If you would like to add information to your original question, you can use the 'edit' link below it. When the issues with the question are addressed it can be reopened (ie. not a question that relies on opinion, focused on one specific topic, and explained clearly and in detail, with images that explain your question - more information [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: I cannot be any clearer about what I want to know, you guys are obviously more concerned about how pretty your forum looks than answering a simple question. Don't worry about it, I'm sure I can either find the correct information somewhere else or I can simply go over to 3DS, I'm sure the guys at Autodesk would be happy to answer me sympathetically.